# Working with PNG Format

Tags: c#, c++, bitmap, png

I am looking to work with PNG format inside of either C++ or C#. I can't find any documentation on how to convert a PNG into a 2D array of bytes/floats which represent the colors on the image.

What I want to achieve:

- Load Png to array [Width*Height]
- Use PNG as a texture inside of a game

If someone could supply me with any documentation, source code or a C#/C++ library/dll that would be great.

Preferrably as C++ and without using any Windows specific library.

Comment: What's wrong with libpng?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: you have tagged C#, yet you are preferably asking for platform-independent C++ library. Why, what's your use scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use libpng, the official PNG library.](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)

Specifically, [this page](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter13.html) has all of the information on how to open and read.

Answer (score 1):

For documentation on anything "standard" thing which is widely used, [Wikipedia is usually the best first stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics). From there you can either read the Wikipedia article, or skip right to [External Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#External_links) section.

For C# code, see for example: [Reading a PNG image file in .Net 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100247/reading-a-png-image-file-in-net-2-0) . As far as I can tell, it's old enough to be part of the ECMA-standardized version of C#, so should be available also on Mono.

Answer (score 1):

In C, [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) is the canonical way.
In C#, you can try [PngCs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/).