# Embed Logo in QR Code

Tags: asp.net, qr-code

I am working on an Asp.Net application where I am generating QR Codes using https://qrcodenet.codeplex.com

Now, one of the requirements are to embed logo in these QR codes. Can anyone please suggest something?

Comment: What is th output format of the QR code generator?

Comment: it will be png format

Answer (score 0):

If the output is in the file system, then it has to read from there and the logo has to be inserted manually in code. However note that embedding the logo reduces useful information in the QR code and mainly works because some error-correction in the reader is in effect; it is not something that is intended to be done.

Reading a PNG file to some suitable data structure is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100247/reading-a-png-image-file-in-net-2-0).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to COVER a QR Code with an image you can exploit its error correction mechanism. There are four levels:
Level L - 7% of codewords can be restored.
Level M - 15% of codewords can be restored.
Level Q - 25% of codewords can be restored.
Level H - 30% of codewords can be restored.
So e.g. if you generate a QR Code with error correction level M you can COVER up-to 15% of the QR Code. 
Try not to cover the functional patterns (e.g. the markers).

A warning that is presented in the link you included:

> If QrCode lose error correction, then it shouldn't exist. Simple as
>   that. Error correction protects QrCode to be able to read from bad
>   environment, or damaged code. While Artistic approach will destroy it.